# Rails 3 scope, combine condition with aggregate (sum) results in error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, aggregate, arel

I am having what I think is a simple problem chaining two scopes (Rails 3.2.5).

I have a model called `Point` with fields `amount` and `transaction_date`, amongst other.  Users get an amount of points for various activities, and they are "available" until used, which happens as part of a transaction, at which point `transaction_date` is updated, and no longer empty.

So I have a scope like this:

```
scope :available, where("transaction_date IS NULL OR transaction_date = ''")
```

and it works great, returning the proper collection of Point objects.  So I can do

```
> Point.available
=> [#<Point id: 123, amount: 22, transaction_date: nil >][#<Point id: 456, amount: 33, transaction_date: nil >]
```

And if I want to know the sum of available points, I can do

```
> Point.available.sum("amount")
=> 55
```

But if I try to make another scope like

```
scope :available, where("transaction_date IS NULL OR transaction_date = ''")
scope :total_available, available.sum("amount")
```

I get the error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `default_scoped?' for 22:Fixnum
```

or if I change the scope so it's `sum("amount").available` I get the error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `available' for 55:Fixnum
```

I can also make the `:total_available` scope work by adding the condition defined in `:available`, but that's not very DRY.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression  `available.sum` gets evaluate straight away so your attempts are equivalent to

```
scope :total_available, 55
```

Or

```
scope :total_available, 55.available
```

Which is clearly wrong. Personally I'd use a class method for this

```
def self.total_available
  available.sum(:amount)
end
```

I think of scopes as a scoped collection: it doesn't make sense to me for scopes to be numbers - for one thing they'd be scopes you couldn't chain other scoped onto

Comment: Thanks @Frederick Chung -- Thanks for the explanation of the errors, that helps me understand the failure.  I also think your solution is practical and your reasoning for its use logical.  However, scopes are implemented in AREL and [documented here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#calculations) and show a case sort of similar to mine -- chaining used as additional refinement.  Maybe my question should be "Is there a right way for Rails?" to use scopes with aggregates like `sum`?

Comment: I can see examples there of running calculations on scopes but not of defining a scope that is a calculation

Comment: Yeah, clearly they are a little different than regular scopes.  And anyway your solution works almost identically to a scope.